# git prompting for username and password

Tags: windows, git

I recently upgraded git and apparently broke something. Now, whenever git tries to interact with my server (Bitbucket) I'm getting an error message and prompted for username and password.  EVERY time.

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
git: 'credential-manager-core' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

I have my git config set for user.name and user.email (this all worked before the upgrade), but I believe this error is blocking git from putting my credentials into the Credential Manager. I presume I have a bad config file somewhere but haven't been able to find it.

Comment: I've had the same problem recently when I try to use Git in my cygwin terminal, but it's been working fine in my Git for Windows bash terminal. Can you indicate which type of window you're working in and which version of Git?

Comment: And, for what it's worth, you might need to install https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core or update Git for Windows, if that's the Git version you're using.

Comment: FYI, the user.name and user.email config have nothing to do with credentials. They're used to determine the information that goes into commits you make, not to connect to remote servers using push/fetch/pull.

Comment: Of potential interest, but only if you're working in Cygwin: I just tried `export PATH=/c/Program\ Files/Git/bin:$PATH` inside my cygwin shell, and then `git` started invoking Git for Windows and stopped asking for my password. However, I'm hoping someone also knows how to fix the issue within cygwin's Git installation.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out credential-manager-core.exe was missing from the git bin folder. I ended up uninstalling Git, manually clearing out the folders and then reinstalling.

Thanks everyone for the suggestions, got me looking in the right direction!